# Do stators in axial flow compressors have airfoil geometry?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, compressors, jet

In axial flow compressors the role of a stator is to gradually change the direction of flow to exchange some of the kinetic energy of the flow into pressure. Therefore it stands to reason that they do not require an airfoil shape, since they're not accelerating the air, unlike the rotor blade. So, are stator blades just curved plates without camber?

Comment: So which manufacturers drawings / designs have you checked?

Comment: Having spent a working lifetime at a jet engine manufacturer, "just curved plates without camber" sounds like a typical "naïve aerodynamicist's" concept of a design that ignores stress and vibration issues. By the time you have made your "ideal infinitely thin curved plate" actually survive in real life without breaking or failing from fatigue cracks, it will look pretty much like a (thin) airfoil.

Answer (score 1):

As @alephzero commented , the stator vanes look just like rotor blades. Both for gas turbine compressors and air compressors. Of coarse attachments and foil shapes are different.And so are the stator vanes in the turbine hot section and a steam turbine .